# Flutter Jiffy Package DateTime

Tags: flutter, datetime

i am using jiffy package to display datetime. with my code below, the dayInfo is showing both 'YESTERDAY' before and after crossing 0000hrs. i have attached the message list code and a screenshot showing what i am facing. i also note that when i send the message after 0000 hours just now, the banner was 'TODAY', and when i came out and back, it changed to 'YESTERDAY'. am i doing something wrong here?

[image]

```
class __DateLabelState extends State<_DateLabel> {
  late String dayInfo;

  @override
  void initState() {
    final createdAt = Jiffy(widget.dateTime);
    final now = DateTime.now();

    if (Jiffy(createdAt).isSame(now, Units.DAY)) {
      dayInfo = 'TODAY';
    } else if (Jiffy(createdAt)
        .isSame(now.subtract(const Duration(days: 1)), Units.DAY)) {
      dayInfo = 'YESTERDAY';
    } else if (Jiffy(createdAt).isAfter(
      now.subtract(const Duration(days: 7)),
      Units.DAY,
    )) {
      dayInfo = createdAt.EEEE;
    } else if (Jiffy(createdAt).isAfter(
      Jiffy(now).subtract(years: 1),
      Units.DAY,
    )) {
      dayInfo = createdAt.MMMd;
    } else {
      dayInfo = createdAt.MMMd;
    }

    super.initState();
  }
```

MessageList

```
class _MessageList extends StatelessWidget {
  const _MessageList({
    Key? key,
    required this.messages,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final List<Message> messages;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: ListView.separated(
        itemCount: messages.length + 1,
        reverse: true,
        separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
          if (index == messages.length - 1) {
            return _DateLabel(dateTime: messages[index].createdAt);
          }
          if (messages.length == 1) {
            return const SizedBox.shrink();
          } else if (index >= messages.length - 1) {
            return const SizedBox.shrink();
          } else if (index <= messages.length) {
            final message = messages[index];
            final nextMessage = messages[index + 1];
            if (!Jiffy(message.createdAt.toLocal())
                .isSame(nextMessage.createdAt.toLocal(), Units.DAY)) {
              return _DateLabel(
                dateTime: message.createdAt,
              );
            } else {
              return const SizedBox.shrink();
            }
          } else {
            return const SizedBox.shrink();
          }
        },
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          if (index < messages.length) {
            final message = messages[index];
            if (message.user?.id == context.currentUser?.id) {
              return _MessageOwnTile(message: message);
            } else {
              return _MessageTile(message: message);
            }
          } else {
            return const SizedBox.shrink();
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I checked your code, but I can't find issue. For example: Restarted application in 67ms.
2022-07-26 00:00:00.000
TODAY
Restarted application in 85ms.
2022-07-26 23:59:00.000
TODAY
Restarted application in 89ms.
2022-07-25 23:59:00.000
YESTERDAY
Restarted application in 73ms.
2022-07-24 23:59:00.000
Sunday

Comment: All my test is correct.

Comment: Try to check you widget.dateTime.

Comment: @igdmitrov what do you mean by that?

Comment: I mean maybe you pass incorrect date time to widget.

Comment: @igdmitrov it is correct, i printed it out on the terminal. but i don't get why it only happens from 0000 to 1000 my local time

Comment: I recorded short video how it works by me.

Comment: https://youtu.be/_MGEjWv0niE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to anyone having this issue as well, just add .toLocal() when returning and you will get the correct datetime banner.

```
class _MessageList extends StatelessWidget {
  const _MessageList({
    Key? key,
    required this.messages,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final List<Message> messages;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: ListView.separated(
        itemCount: messages.length + 1,
        reverse: true,
        separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
          if (index == messages.length - 1) {
            return _DateLabel(dateTime: messages[index].createdAt.toLocal());
          }
          if (messages.length == 1) {
            return const SizedBox.shrink();
          } else if (index >= messages.length - 1) {
            return const SizedBox.shrink();
          } else if (index <= messages.length) {
            final message = messages[index];
            final nextMessage = messages[index + 1];
            if (!Jiffy(message.createdAt.toLocal())
                .isSame(nextMessage.createdAt.toLocal(), Units.DAY)) {
              return _DateLabel(
                dateTime: message.createdAt.toLocal(),
              );
            } else {
              return const SizedBox.shrink();
            }
          } else {
            return const SizedBox.shrink();
          }
        },
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          if (index < messages.length) {
            final message = messages[index];
            if (message.user?.id == context.currentUser?.id) {
              return _MessageOwnTile(message: message);
            } else {
              return _MessageTile(message: message);
            }
          } else {
            return const SizedBox.shrink();
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```